# Powershell save selected range as html in excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to save a selected range only in excel as html file. I managed to select the range i wanted to save as html but I am getting error message below when trying to save it:

Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'SaveAs'.

Below is the complete script i have.

```
set-itemproperty "cms.xlsm" -Name Attributes -Value "ReadOnly" 
$file = "cms.xlsm"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel")|Out-Null
$excel = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
$excel.Visible = $True 
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false 
$wb = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet



$rangeAc = $ws.Range(“B2:P119”)
$rangeAc.select()
$rangeselect = $rangeAc
$xlHTML = 44
$rangeselect.SaveAs("index.html",$xlHTML) #save workbook as extension
```

Would greatly appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: are you trying to get data and output a html ?

Comment: That's right, data from existing file which is cms.xlsm, from line 2

Comment: What you are after is `$rangeselect.Application.ActiveSheet.SaveAs("index.html",$xlHTML)`. This is because you are in a `ComObject` and need to specify your way down the line. I recommend using `| Get-Member` to see what you can do with each variable you are using.